# Crash on animation: ERROR: 'this' is not available

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to setup a "sliding button", I want my button(*button1*), to slide left on click on it,  but Android Studio shows me the message:

> mButtonTranslator = 'this' is not available

The inherent code is this below:

```
mButtonTranslator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0,90);
mButtonTranslator.addUpdateListener((animatedValue)->{
    float distanceTraveled = (float)animatedValue.getAnimatedValue();
    button1.setTranslationX(distanceTraveled);
});
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37968162/3395198

Comment: Thanks but 'Build Variants' tab is already on "Debug"

Comment: SOLVED: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44695239/using-float-value-in-valueanimator-causes-exception/44695473#comment76568639_44695473